# Blackberry permissions to connect internet after signing?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

While working with Browser Field in Blackberry the code is working when running in simulator before signing. But after signing app is not working, means webpage is not loading.. code is as follows...

code:

```
   public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
  { 
    public MyScreen()
    {        

    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("MyTitle");

    ButtonField bf = new ButtonField("google");
    bf.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            Dialog.alert("this is button click");                               
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {                   
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();
                    add(browserField);
                    browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.com");
                }
            }, 2000, false);
        }
    });       

    add(bf);


}

}
```

As per the following code, if i am executing it in **simulator before signing** working good & website is loading. But **after signing my app with signing keys** and if i am executing in device, it is not executing means website is not loading, just blank page is displaying.

**Not getting what is the problem with my app before & after signing.** 
After searching in internet, got some information that we need to pass some suffixes to work after signing, in devices when using HTTPconnections like

```
    HttpConnection httpConn;
    StreamConnection s;
    String url;
    s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url+";deviceside=true");
```

But if i am passing the same code in browser field means it is concatenating with the given url like..

```
   browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.com" + ";deviceside=true");
```

and getting error like unable to find "http://www.google.com;deviceside=true"

**so, can anyone please suggest me how to access internet using browser field after blackberry applications are signed.**

My app needs to support OS 6.0 & 7.0

Comment: you can open www.google.com on your mobile browser ?

Comment: here for example i gave google url but in my app i am using other url which needs to be loaded by users choice... After getting problem with my app, i tried this example and even it is also getting the same problem after signing. so, i posted this question...

Comment: buddy, any website is opening on your browser ?. not via your app, open any site directly entering the url.

Comment: That's true, but after signing browser is not loading & getting as "http://www.google.com has been timed out". if i am executing the app in simulator without signing it is working good.

Comment: @user1540872 Signare wants to know whether you are getting internet on your phone. Does the internet work on your phone?

Comment: Actually my app consists of some server side data, if i am checking in simulator before signing working good but after signing, not working. i am passing html file in browser field like bwf.requestContent("local:///html/index.html"); & all the server code is in javascript files.

Comment: ya, normally getting internet..... i am accessing it.....

Comment: please tell us which minimum OS version your app needs to support.  include that information with virtually every question you ask about BlackBerry development.  it's very important.

Comment: my app needs to support OS 6.0....

Answer (score 0):

try this code -

```
    String url="http://www.google.com";
    BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
    myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
    browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
    add(browserField);
    browserField.requestContent(url);
```

Comment: I executed this code also & working good in simulator before signing. But after signing, it is not executing in device. Not getting internet access after signing. that is the problem facing by me....

Comment: go to options-third party applications - edit the permissions on your phone, then allow all the permissions and try.

Comment: To change the `ConnectionFactory` instance used by `BrowserFeild`, you need to use `myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONNECTION_FACTORY, customizedConnectionFactoryInstance);`. Check BlackBerry API Documentation for `ConnectionFactory`, link here, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/.